# Перенос проекта с VS 6.0 на VS Express 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++, visual-studio

Очень долгое время пользовался для разработки программы на С++ Visual Studio 6.0. Никаких проблем не было, поэтому и смысла апгрейдиться для себя не видел. Недавно установил новую Windows 8.1 и старая VS 6.0 на ней работать отказалась - вылетает при запуске. Установил Visual Studio Express 2013. Попробовал открыть в ней этот проект. Студия начала его конвертировать к новой версии, успешно сконвертировала, открыла и вместо проекта написала "несовместимо".

Попробовал создать новый пустой проект. Максимум что нашел похожего - это "Пустое приложение (универсальные приложения)". Однако, при этом создается проект из трех пунктов включая Windows Phone с совершенно другой структурой папок. А мне не нужен такой проект, мне нужно просто продолжать разрабатывать свою программу для настольных Windows (конечно же включая и старые версии вроде XP).

Как перенести старый проект и продолжать работать с ним? Нужно скачивать какую-то другую студию? Или нужно в этой выбрать что-то другое?

Comment: А почему бы просто не создать новый проект, и не подключить к нему все исходники из старого?

Comment: @VladD, а как? Я во втором абзаце описал свою попытку это сделать... У меня не получилось. Надо как-то иначе?

Comment: Экспресс версии идут для разных языков. Может вы скачали для c# или для с++/CLI. В них код писать можно, но это не совсем то, что Вам нужно (что бы там Майкрософт не говорила).

Comment: @BArtWell: У вас Express 2013 for Windows Desktop? Если нет, скачайте его.

Comment: Вы правы, ключевое слово здесь "Desktop". Скачал другую версию и все заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: а чтоб подключить - в меню создания проекта укаажите галочку Empty Project, добавляйте файлы и тестируйте